# can't use password field firefox

Tags: javascript

This is the html for my page

```
<form id="sign-up">
    <label class="col-lg-4 col-md-3">First Name</label>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <input type="" name="" class="form-control" id="first-name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 label-padding"></div>

    <label class="col-lg-4 col-md-3">Last Name</label>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <input type="" name="" class="form-control" id="last-name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 label-padding"></div>

    <label class="col-lg-4 col-md-3">Username</label>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <input type="" name="" class="form-control" id="username" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 label-padding">
        <span class="error-message username-exists hidden">Username Exists</span>
    </div> 

    <label class="col-lg-4 col-md-3">Email</label>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <input type="email" name="" class="form-control" id="email" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 label-padding">
        <span class="error-message email-exists hidden">Email Exists</span>
    </div>

    <label class="col-lg-4 col-md-3">Password</label>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <input type="password" name="" class="form-control" id="pswd" placeholder="Minimum password length: 8 chars" required>
        <p class="error-message hidden password-error">Password too short.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 label-padding"></div>

    <label class="col-lg-4 col-md-3">Confirm Password</label>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 label-padding">
        <input type="password" name="" class="form-control" id="pswd-2" placeholder="repeat password" required>
        <p class="error-message hidden password-mismatch-error">Passwords don't match.</p>
    </div>
```

it has a bug in firefox where I can't on the modal type into the password field. To show this issue well enough I recorded it so you can see on the form looping with tab skips the field (and I also can't click the field).

https://youtu.be/PyG1KM6_jzY

Comment: which one? both the password or anyone?

Comment: only the password, including the repeat password. I can use the other fields.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: @Srdjan yes my ubuntu is that version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `Ubuntu 18.04` operating system you're using combined with Firefox.

The problem is solved if you install the available package by 
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=8974077

Here is the origin of the `.deb`
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1405634

Hopefully, the bug will soon be fixed in Ubuntu, in the meantime, you can install the package fix.

Comment: thanks your right it worked in windows. will keep checking new ubuntu firefox updates